# Pushing pictures with push notifications (ngCordova, Angular, Ionic)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Recently, I have come across some apps, that are able to show me a picture (in addition to some text) in the application drawer / lock screen when a push notification arrives. I would like to know if it is possible to implement this with Ionic / Angular / ngCordova stack.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the PushNotification retrieves the image property, I think the local notification is not able to display an image at the moment.

The question has already been asked in the cordova-plugin-local-notifications plugin GitHub Issues:
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/issues/536
but it hasn't been answered.