# Image push notification angularjs/ionic

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification

I just want to know that is it possible to have image push notifications in ionic ,As i found some links but they are not  answered yet

Here are links :-

1) [Sending image in push notification to Android phones using phonegap plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34409775/sending-image-in-push-notification-to-android-phones-using-phonegap-plugin)

2) [Pushing pictures with push notifications (ngCordova, Angular, Ionic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272971/pushing-pictures-with-push-notifications-ngcordova-angular-ionic)

If , yes then can anyone give me reference link

Thanks

Comment: have you done it? I used that payload but image is not shown.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can send Image in push Notification in Cordova. If you are using [Phonegap push plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) take a look at - [Push notification payload details](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#picture-messages),

```
{
    "registration_ids": ["my device id"],
    "data": {
        "title": "Big Picture",
        "message": "This is my big picture message",
        "style": "picture",
        "picture": "http://36.media.tumblr.com/c066cc2238103856c9ac506faa6f3bc2/tumblr_nmstmqtuo81tssmyno1_1280.jpg",
        "summaryText": "The internet is built on cat pictures"
    }
}
```

You can see that the attribute `image` is used to send [Large-icon](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#images) in Notification panel. If you want to sent Big-picture or Image in Notification use 
 `"style" : "picture"` and sent picture URL with Summary text.

Comment: Is there any way to do it form ionic dashboard? In payload field of ionic dashboard, I used these pairs but it received just like normal notification.